# duda con respuesta con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Se tiene la siguiente validación con ajax, la idea es realizar una validación de un campo con un tabla.
mediante la siguiente función envio los parametros

```
function val_tipo_venta(c_almacen,c_tipo_venta){
    ajax=nuevoAjax();
    ajax.open('POST','ajax_validar_alm.php',true);

    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (ajax.readyState==4){
            console.log(ajax.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.send('&c_almacen='+c_almacen+'&c_tipo_venta='+c_tipo_venta);
    return false;        
}
```

Archivo que realiza la consulta. ajax_validar_alm.php

```
$c_almacen=$_POST['c_almacen'];
$tipo_venta=$_POST['c_tipo_venta'];
?>


<?php

$miret=0;
$sql = "select campo1 from tabla
         WHERE campo1= ".$c_almacen."
           AND camo2=".$c_tipo_venta."";
p_query($sql);
$registro = f_next_row($g_idq);
if( !$registro ){ return 0 }
?>
```

el realiza una consulta y si no hay resultado retorna 0

luego en otra funcion intento obtener el valor de esta funcion, pero siempre me traer undefined

```
var sw_respuesta= val_tipo_venta(almacen,tipo_venta);
if(sw_respuesta==0){
    alert("El tipo de venta seleccionado, no esta relacionado al almacen,por favor  realiza la configuración en el maestro de tipos de venta.");
    return false;
}
```

¿esta bien de esta forma o estoy haciendo algo mal?

Answer (score 0):

creo que estas imprimiendo mal el retorno, para poder ver esto podrías hacer un console.log(sw_respuesta);

lo otro que podrias hacer es desde tu php devolver un tipo json y esto seria algo asi

```
return  ["status" => 1 , "mensaje" => "tu mensaje aqui"];
```

y desde tu archivo ajax lo tomarías de la siguiente forma.

```
sw_respuestas.mensaje o sw_respuestas.status.
```

espero que te sea de ayuda.